# DD50 equivalent?

Tags: cables, wire

I've been looking around and can't find a definitive answer, so I figured I'd ask here. 
I'm completely new to electronics. This past Fourth of July I made a simple firework launcher using DB15 as the cable between the control unit and the ignition unit. This worked, but I could only connect 14 fuses at once.

So now I'm looking to improve for next year and one of my first issues is getting more wires in one cable. I was considering the DB50 (or DD50 in someplaces). But if I wanted to get 50', I would be paying around $150. I was wondering if there is another cable that offers around this many 1:1 connections.

I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: Pro firework technicians use serial links. I work with a guy and that's what he told me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andy says, pro installations use serial communications, with multiple breakout boxes near the launchers.

But if you really want to go parallel, just google "multi-pair telephone cable". You can use cat2 or cat3 cable in this sort of application. 25-pair cable (50 conductors) is less than $1/foot, and 100-pair (200 conductors) is less than $3/foot.

Comment: Yep. You can often find surplus 25 pair cable with centronics connectors on it as well, it was used in telephony a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the arrangement will not need to last long, nor survive many attach-detach cycles, consider using computer hard disk type UDMA-IDE PATA/4 80-conductor ribbon cables, and the corresponding UDMA-IDE connectors. If those conductors are not hefty enough for the fuses, the older 40-core standard IDE cables have thicker conductors.

[image: IDE cables] <sub>(*[image source](http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleid=1778&page=3)*)</sub>

You can get Insulation Displacement Connectors for IDE pretty inexpensively, and the ribbon cable itself is sold in 10 meter and larger rolls by various online vendors.

If you need the cable to be in a round profile, rather than flat, funnel-shaped adapters and round cable sleeves are available:

[image: IDE round cable] <sub>(*[image source](http://en.esskabel.de/kabelkonfektion/C100/)*)</sub>